# How can i acces a map inside of an atom map?

Tags: clojure

i am trying to acces a map inside an atom map. I have this:

```
(def database (atom {:henk {:username "henk" :password "johnson" :session "test"}
:steve {:username "steve" :password "boldwin" :session "test2"}
:cane {:username "cane" :password "john" :session "test3"}}))
```

I have tried using swap! inside dosync but i can't seem to access desired value.
Can you help me?

Comment: what do you actually need to access? if you only need "read" method, then swap is not necessary.

Comment: Actually i need to change the value of session...

Comment: @happy_list Updated my answer with modification example.

Comment: Alexey, thank you very much. Best wishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 user=> (def database (atom {:henk {:username "henk" :password "johnson" :session "test"}
                             :steve {:username "steve" :password "boldwin" :session "test2"}
                             :cane {:username "cane" :password "john" :session "test3"}}))
 #'user/database
 user=> (:henk @database)
 {:session "test", :username "henk", :password "johnson"}
```

To modify:

```
user=> (swap! database assoc-in [:henk :session] "test + swap")
{:cane {:session "test3", :username "cane", :password "john"}, 
 :henk {:session "test + swap", :username "henk", :password "johnson"}, 
 :steve {:session "test2", :username "steve", :password "boldwin"}}
```

Check that value is updated:

```
user=> @database
{:cane {:session "test3", :username "cane", :password "john"}, 
 :henk {:session "test + swap", :username "henk", :password "johnson"}, 
 :steve {:session "test2", :username "steve", :password "boldwin"}}
```